# Does Go support nested type declarations or literal assignments to anonymous structs?

Tags: go, struct, types, literals

I'm new to Go and have two questions about types.

For example, take this code:

```
type Rule struct {
    handler func() (err error)
    creator string
    args struct {
        extension string
        action string
        folder struct {
            location string
            storage string
        }
    }
}
```

1) How can I create a new `Rule` using a **single** literal declaration and assign values to the properties of `args`? What is wrong with this code:

```
rule := Rule{
    args: {
        extension: "png,jpg,gif,svg",
        action: "move",
    },
}
```

2) Is it possible to define types within types? For instance, without breaking the code into two separate type declarations, could I modify the `args` portion of the `Rule` type so that it defines a second type called `RuleArgs`?

I know that I **can** break these out into multiple assignments and declarations, but my question is do I have to (ie. does Go make it impossible not to)?

Comment: 1. The args value should be typed https://play.golang.org/p/v0HxXoM0Sf- 2. No

Comment: Thank you for the full example using my types. Do you have a reference for 2? If so, please add an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to refer to something that is not in the spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested structs are a thing in go, but they can induce some messiness. To instantiate the given object, try this:

```
type Rule struct {
    handler func() (err error)
    creator string
    args struct {
        extension string
        action string
    }
}

rule := Rule{
    args: struct {
        extension string
        action    string
    }{
        extension: "png,jpg,gif,svg",
        action:    "move",
    },
}
```

Notice that I have the structure's argument names and types listed. Also note I removed the `folder` argument for brevity.

If you want to do it in multiple lines:

```
rule2 := Rule{}
rule2.args.action = "some-action"
```

Comment: This would not be assignable to `Rule`

Comment: I've left my comment **before** you provided the changed structure. My comment addresses the fact that your solution would not work for the OP's types.

Comment: Thank you poy, that clarifies my first question. If you can expand with an answer for the second question (I'm looking for a reference) I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for the comment. I added a note.

Comment: @moismailzai I appended to the answer.

Comment: I added that a second part to the answer